# Cygwin as native 64-bit in the future?

Tags: cygwin

Does anyone know if there will ever be a true 64-bit version of Cygwin?  The FAQ says "as far as we know nobody is working on a 64-bit version" or something like that.  Is cygwin forever to be a 32-bit application (or family of apps if you prefer)?

A 64-bit version would be nice.  For the most part I can do what I need with the 32-bit version of cygwin on 64-bit windows.  But every now and then a 64-bit program I launch from cygwin will recognize the fact that it was launched by a 32-bit parent and behave incorrectly, or not run at all.  I must open a cmd.exe or powershell session to run these few commands.  One example you can reproduce for yourelf on Windows 2003 64-bit with IIS installed is to run the following command from cygwin then from a cmd.exe that was not opened from within cygwin.  (Double backslashes obviously aren't necessary in cmd.exe, but they work ok in both shells.)

cscript c:\\windows\\system32\\iisApp.vbs

So, I can live with opening a cmd.exe session when I need to run something that behaves this way.  But being a huge fan of Cygwin I would really like to see an indication that someday someone will produce a 64-bit version.

Comment: It feels like I've been using cygwin forever--I think my first installation was under Windows NT 3.51. (I could be wrong about that.) But when I look five years into the future, I think I'm more likely to be running Windows and some version of Linux in a VM.

Comment: The Cygwin FAQ is written, in large part, by the same people who are most likely to do the work you're wanting to see. Either you did not know that when you asked this question, or you are expecting someone here to have a different answer, which I guess would mean that there is a stealth 64-bit rewrite going on somewhere that the Cygwin core devs don't know about.

Comment: OK, Warren, you caught me. Actually I really didn't expect a different answer here. I was more looking for what the reaction would be, maybe sort of find out if I was the only one who was concerned.

Comment: Its just been released now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably coincidence, but shortly after this question was posted, there was a large thread with the Cygwin developers discussing 64-bit here:

http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.os.cygwin.devel/233/focus=247

TL;DR - They are in fact thinking about 64-bit Cygwin, but the porting issues are complex...

Comment: Thanks for that info and link Josh.  I am glad to know that it is being considered.  I think if Cygwin will live on into the distant future (which I hope it will) it will be necessary at some point.  Imagine if it was 16 bit.  Would anyone use it?  Will anyone still use 32 bit applications 5 years from now?

Comment: I'm sure 32-bit will eventually go away, but I'm not brave enough to predict when... ;)

Comment: 64bit Cygwin will be available in the near future. Corinna, the Cygwin maintainer, and others are currently busy building 64 bit packages. See the mailing list: http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-developers/2013-03/

Comment: 64-bit Cygwin has now been officially released: http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2013-07/msg00438.html.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to see a clairvoyant to get a defininitive answer to your question, but here goes anyway.

A 64-bit Cygwin is certainly possible, but it would require a lot of work. That involves not only adapting the Cygwin DLL, which probably contains many 32-bit assumptions, but also the porting of all the packages in the distro. My guess is that this will happen when 64-bit Windows becomes so widespread that developing the 32-bit version is no longer worthwhile, so as to avoid splitting the Cygwin project's rather limited resources.

Comment: Unfortunately (?) 64-bit Windows can run 32-bit Cygwin just fine, so developing the 32-bit version will be worthwhile for a long time from now.